# Here Maps "These credentials do not authorize access"

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, here-api

I am trying to get data from here.com API and it keeps returning `401` error.

```
{"error":"Unauthorized","error_description":"These credentials do not authorize access"}
```

[image: one]

#### Code

```
$minutes = 60;
$forecast = Cache::remember('forecast', $minutes, function () {
    $app_id = env('HERE_APP_ID');
    $app_code = env('HERE_APP_CODE');
    $lat = env('HERE_LAT_DEFAULT');
    $lng = env('HERE_LNG_DEFAULT');
    $url = "https://weather.api.here.com/weather/1.0/report.json?product=forecast_hourly&latitude=${lat}&longitude=${lng}&oneobservation=true&language=in&app_id=${app_id}&app_code=${app_code}";

    Log::info($url);


    $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $res = $client->get($url);
    if ($res->getStatusCode() == 200) {
        $j = $res->getBody();
        $obj = json_decode($j);
        $forecast = $obj->hourlyForecasts->forecastLocation;
    }
    return $forecast;
});
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: try this url `$url = "https://weather.api.here.com/weather/1.0/report.json?product=forecast_hourly&latitude=$lat&longitude=$lng&oneobservation=true&language=in&app_id=$app_id&app_code=$app_code";`

Comment: @KamleshPaul same error

Comment: then go to `weather` api dashboard and enable that service

Comment: is there separate dashboard for weather?

Comment: where did you get that api key ? https://developer.here.com/documentation/destination-weather/dev_guide/topics/credentials-auth-options.html

Answer (score 2):

The correct API endpoint to use with an **API Key** is not `https://weather.api.here.com` but `https://weather.ls.hereapi.com/`.

For example:

```
 https://weather.ls.hereapi.com/weather/1.0/report.json?apiKey=YOUR-API-KEY&product=alerts&name=Paris
```